Can RTK GPS Be Used in Webots Simulation?
Is it possible to use Real-Time Kinematic (RTK) GPS in Webots simulation? I need to implement RTK GPS in Webots as per my supervisor's requirements. From what I’ve gathered, Webots appears to support only standard GPS and not RTK. Apologies if this is a basic question; I’m new to Webots.

You can use the standard GPS, just make sure to set the correct noise (e.g. 1cm). From the simulation perspective, the RTK fix will just make the standard GPS less noisy.
